# MySQL sorting string values with numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

My data is like this:

```
KRYPTON-4xLV
KRYPTON-3xSTG
KRYPTON-16xTH
KRYPTON-8xTH
KRYPTON-8xLV
```

When I call `ORDER BY` on this column the values are sorted like this:

```
KRYPTON-16xTH
KRYPTON-3xSTG
KRYPTON-4xLV
KRYPTON-8xLV
KRYPTON-8xTH
```

Is there a way to sort this like?

```
KRYPTON-4xLV
KRYPTON-8xLV
KRYPTON-3xSTG
KRYPTON-8xTH
KRYPTON-16xTH
```

Here is the SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d061/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select code
from (select *, substring(code, LOCATE('-', code) + 1, length(code)) o from products )t
order by 
substring(o, LOCATE('x', o), length(code)),
cast(o as UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: Close but still not quite as expected. Here are the results of your edit: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d061/12. Not even sure if it's possible to sort the way I expect. See my question...

Comment: @PrimozRome, you are not sorting by numbers... Why 3 is between 2 eights and not the first?

Comment: It can be first, what I want to do is to keep "identical products" together sorted by number. For example KRYPTON-4xLV, KRYPTON-8xLV should sort one after another. Same goes for KRYPTON-8xTH should be followed by KRYPTON-16xTH. So modules that end with TH, LV, XYZ should be sorted together by number that comes before that (3x, 4x, 8x). I hope you understand my need?

Comment: @PrimozRome, ok I've got it.